# Using xsplash in ubuntu lucid 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub, xorg

Is there a way of using xsplash in ubuntu lucid 10.04? I know there's lots of information out there on the internet stating its impossible, but as we all know, nothing is impossible. If there's a step-by-step method which involves hacking grub or X11 server, I wouldn't mind getting my hands dirty! This whole process would be virtualized, so there will be no major harm to my actual host operating system. Let me know!